# Array of Fibonacci values; Value of high index turns array value into negative

Tags: java, arrays, fibonacci

I created an array called numbers that will store values of a Fibonacci sequence. 1, 2, 3, 5, etc. 
The problem is that when I try to call the array value at a very high index value, the array value becomes negative.

```
numbers[10] = 144
```

which is reasonable but

```
numbers[9999998] = -1448735941
```

Any help?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] numbers = new int[10000000];

    numbers[0] = 1;
    numbers[1] = 2;

    for(int x = 2; x<=numbers.length-1; x++)
    {
        numbers[x] = numbers[x-1] + numbers[x-2];
    }

    System.out.println(numbers[9999998]);
    System.out.println(numbers[10]);
```

Comment: @Jeffrey You should post that as the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Overflow. Once the value exceeds the maximum 'capacity' of the 32bit int, the result will wrap around and start from the minimum value (a negative).

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

long and BigInteger are able to store higher values than int.

Answer (score 3):

You are experiencing [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow). Take a look at [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) for one workaround.